# Effective way of replacing containsKey check with methods introduced in java8 for Map

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

Following is a java program that uses a Map to compute number of occurrences of letters in a String:

```
String str = "babbaceeeeee";
    Map<String,Integer> letterCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int count =0; count<str.length(); count++){
        String letter = str.substring(count, count +1);
        if(letterCountMap.containsKey(letter)){
            int presentCount = letterCountMap.get(letter);
            letterCountMap.put(letter, presentCount + 1);
        }else{
            letterCountMap.put(letter, 1);
        }

        
    }
    System.out.println("letterCountMap ::"+letterCountMap);//prints letterCountMap ::{a=2, b=3, c=1, e=6}
```

Is there a way to effectively replace this code with a combination of methods introduced in Java8 for Map like compute(), computeIfPresent(), computeIfAbsent () etc without using containsKey() if condition??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking cue from @Naman's answer to use the merge method and for those not conversant with method reference, a more lucid answer from me:-

```
Map<String,Integer> letterCountMap = new HashMap<>();
for(int count = 0; count<str.length(); count++){
            String letter = str.substring(count, count +1);
            System.out.println("Current letter::"+letter);
            letterCountMap.merge(letter, 1, (a,b)->{
                //System.out.println("a="+a);//current value of corresponding key
                //System.out.println("b="+b);//1 in this case
                return a+b;
            }
            );
             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it using [`Map.merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) on the `Map` instead of the complete `if..else` block such as:

```
letterCountMap.merge(letter, 1, Integer::sum);
```

The overall solution could be simplified to:

```
Map<Character, Integer> letterCountMap = new HashMap<>();
for (char letter : str.toCharArray()) {
    letterCountMap.merge(letter, 1, Integer::sum);
}
```